# Output nth pass for this string sequence

Tags: string, algorithm, bit-manipulation, c++14

You have a string that consists of characters '0' and '1'. Consider the sequence to be '01011010'. Swap places of 0 and 1 if 0 is followed by 1. Output n-th pass of the sequence.

- Pass 1: '10101100'
- Pass 2: '11010100'
- Pass 3: '11101000'
- Pass 4: '11110000'

This seems to be modified bubble sort where we need to output n-th pass.
My algorithm:

```cpp
while (pass != 0)
    begin
        bool x = false;
        int prev = ∞;
        for (int i = 0; i < string_length; i++)
        begin
            if (prev == 0) then
                switch (string[i])
                    case 0:
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        string[i] = 0;
                        string[i-1] = 1;
                        prev = ∞;
                        x = true;
                        break;
            else
                prev = string[i];
            end if
        end
        if (!x) 
            break;
        pass = pass - 1;

    end
```

The output is correct but the algorithm isn't that efficient. The worst case is still O(n^2). Can someone help me in reducing the time complexity ?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the only allowed operation switching two adjacent elements? Otherwise you could just scan the number and count 0's and 1's, then output 1's followed by 0's according the the counts in O(n)

Comment: No but you need to output n-th pass. If string is '10' you cannot swap but you can if the string is '01'

Comment: Yes that is what my suggested algorithm ([CountingSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort)) does

Comment: Counting sort will directly output the sorted string as 11110000 in O(n). What if I want the 3rd pass which is 11101000 ? n is input in n-th pass.

Comment: Ah, now I get it, my bad

Comment: Shouldn't the first pass yield 10110100? Because after the second zero gets swapped with the 1 to its right, it again has a 1 to its right and gets another swap, correct? If that's how it works, there's a linear algorithm.

Comment: nope its not complete bubble sort you need to ignore the updated value

Comment: This is from an active contest that ends 13May: [problem](https://www.codechef.com/MAY19B/problems/BINARY)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible way forward. I understand that this is an ongoing [contest](https://www.codechef.com/MAY19B/problems/BINARY).

Consider the "waiting" period of each 1. We are concerned with 1's that have other 1's directly to their left, for which they have to "wait" before they can start to move; and also with 1's that have not enough zeros to prevent them from additional "waits" when they reach other groups of 1's.

Example:

```
        "waiting" periods
        0 1 2 3     0+3-2+1
        ^ ^ ^ ^     ^ 1+3-2+1
        ^ ^ ^ ^     ^ ^
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1
0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0
1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0
              ^   ^
              ^   5 moves - 3 wait
              ^
              5 moves - 2 wait
```

Using our "waiting" periods, we can calculate where each 1 will end up, although there are more aspects to this, when we consider multiple interruptions and how to figure out in which one any 1 might end up.

Comment: Is it possible to know the effective number of passes like if the string is &#39;0100011110&#39; we require only 7 passes and not 10-1=9. In this case I would traverse from backwards if required pass is more than half.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user9469335 since it is an ongoing contest, I would rather not elaborate, but the truth is I have not thought through to see if this could lead to a viable solution. It was just an idea for a possible way to explore.